# Convert local memory to registers

Tags: opencl

I currently have a kernel that processes a global buffer by reading
into local memory and doing calculations. Now, I would like to use registers
instead of local memory. How do I convert to registers?

Thanks!

Edit:  project can be found here:

https://github.com/boxerab/ocldwt

Comment: Just remove the `__local`. But probably it will not work, since the __local and __private memories are not interchangeable. You need to rewrite the algorithm.

Comment: Also its not advisable to use registers extensively, it may slowdown due to register spilling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing some code, it's impossible to give much more guidance than has already been given but I will try to elaborate on the comments.

Any variable declared without `__local` or `__global` is private, so if you remove the modifier the memory will only be visible to the single processing element running the work item. This will likely be stored in a register, although that will only happen if there is register space available. The compiler will already be putting some values into registers on your behalf, even if you haven't asked it to do so. You can see evidence of this if, for example, you are running on the NVIDIA platform and pass the `-cl-nv-verbose` flag when you build your kernels. You will see output like this:

```
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'monte' for 'sm_35'
ptxas info    : Function properties for monte
 0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 61 registers, 360 bytes cmem[0], 96 bytes cmem[2]
```

indicating that 61 registers are in use.

However, as pointed out by [@DarkZeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079893/convert-local-memory-to-registers#comment39021109_25079893), the decision to move from local memory to private memory is much more about the scope of variables. If your algorithm depends on all of the members of a compute unit having access to the same copy of a variable, then it isn't going to work any more.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I have added a link to the gitub project if you want to take a look at the code.

Comment: No problem, will take a look at it if I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks. Even a quick look to see if I have made any egregious errors would be greatly appreciated!!!!